# Wanting to render the Initials of a customer name in a placeholder icon next to the textfield

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, extjs

`**I will give a whole scenario , I come to a page , it has a search icon , when I click on it , a list of the clients are generated and after a selecting one of the clients , the textfield is getting populated but the placeholder icon is not getting populated with the intials of the client.

Let us say , I select INNOCHRIS SFC from the menu , the INNOCHRIS SFC is populated on the textfield but it is not being reflected on the placeholder icon with the initials "IS" ..

Also , when I go to the next step meaning the next page  , and return to this very step (after clicking back)  again , I see the initals being displayed with "IS" and "INNOCHRIS SFC".

So the desired state is the one mentioned above where upon selection of the client name which is INNOCHRIS SFC . IS should be displayed together. The above image is expected step. I tried debugging have found few methods of c# and EXT JS.**

````
`Here is the C# Code : 
           #region poponField
           string poponFieldIcon = activateUserDisplay ? string.Empty : "popon-info-button";
           poponField.fieldLabel = String.Empty;
           poponField.flex = 1;
           poponField.cls = "axe-basic-field";
           poponField.ACPPoponFieldEntry = XmlUtility.GetAttributeValue(currentFieldXElement, Constant.xmlAttribute.searchentry);
           poponField.ACPParentItemName = itemName;
           poponField.ACPPoponDisplayTitle = XmlUtility.GetDisplayAttributeFromCultureTag(currentFieldXElement, culture.language);
           poponField.ACPItemID = itemID;
           poponField.padding = "8 0 8 0";
           poponField.listeners = (ComboBoxListeners)AddListenersToComponent(poponField.listeners, Helper.GetInstance().GenerateGenericListener("poponfieldInfoFeature"
               , Constant.extJsEventPameters["fieldChange"], null, false), "change", new ComboBoxListeners());
           poponField.listeners = (ComboBoxListeners)AddListenersToComponent(poponField.listeners, Helper.GetInstance().GenerateGenericListener("clearInvalideValueForPoponFiedlOnBlur"
             , Constant.extJsEventPameters["componentBlur"], null, false), "blur", new ComboBoxListeners());
           poponField.ACPUserDisplay = activateUserDisplay;
           fieldcontainer.items.Add(poponField);
           #endregion`
```
#endregion  /// This has a method which contains the references to the javascript code `poponfieldInfoFeature which is Javascript ref`

This method looks like this and calls another reference SetPopFieldCustomDisplay

var poponfieldInfoFeature = function (field, oldValue, newValue, opt) {
    var poponfield = field.up('fieldcontainer');
    var infoButton = poponfield.down('button[itemId=info]');
    if (infoButton) {
        var fieldValue = field.getValue();
        var record = field.findRecordByValue(fieldValue);
        if (record && record.get('REF')) {
            if (acpV9 && field.ACPUserDisplay) SetPoponFieldCustomDisplay(infoButton, null, newValue)
            infoButton.setDisabled(false);
        } else {
            if (acpV9 && field.ACPUserDisplay) infoButton.setText('');
            infoButton.setDisabled(true);
        }
    }
}
////// POPFIELD METHOD ///////

var SetPoponFieldCustomDisplay = function (currentbtn, ept, fieldValue) {
    var len = currentbtn.up().down().xtype == 'poponfield' ? currentbtn.up().down().getStore().data.items.length : 0;
    var poponText = '';
    if (currentbtn.up().down().xtype != 'poponfield' || len != 0) {
        switch (currentbtn.up().down().xtype) {
            case 'poponfield':
                poponText = currentbtn.up().down().getStore().data.items[0].data.TEXT;
                break;
            case 'combobox':
                if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue != '' && currentbtn.up().down().findRecordByValue(fieldValue).data != null) {
                    poponText = currentbtn.up().down().findRecordByValue(fieldValue).data.TEXT;
                } else {
                    poponText = currentbtn.up().down().getValue();
                }
                break;
            default:
                poponText = currentbtn.up().down().getValue();
                break;
        }
    }

    if (poponText != '' && poponText != null) {
        var matches = poponText.match(/\b(\w)/g);
        var acronym = matches.join('');
        acronym = acronym.length > 2 ? acronym.charAt(0) + acronym.charAt(acronym.length - 1) : acronym
        currentbtn.setText(acronym.toLowerCase());
    }
    else
        currentbtn.setText('');
}
**`

So overall here is the flow ---- EXTJSGenerator.cs has several methods to reference the javascript variables , one of which I suspect the poponfieldFeature which in turn references to SetPoponFieldCustomDisplay.
I tried to manipulate the functions SetPoponFieldCustomDisplay  and poponfieldFeature  functions but no lick , could not understand why "Initals are not displayed"" ..  please help me `**
````

Comment: If u can't isolate the problem or create a full functional example for us in stackblitz or in any other online tool, I am afraid we can't help u (or at least me)

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.